# Partitions and JdbcPagingItemReader doesn't gives correct values

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am working on `Spring Batch and Partition using the JdbcPagingItemReader`, but I am only getting half records.

If I am expecting 100 thousand records instead getting only 50 thousand. What's wrong is happening
How to use **Nested or Inner Query** in `OraclePagingQueryProvider` ?

My Original Query

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM (SELECT DEPT.ID id,
               DEPT.CREATOR createdby,
               DEPT.CREATE_DATE createddate,
               DEPT.UPDATED_BY updatedby,
               DEPT.LAST_UPDATE_DATE updateddate,
               DEPT.NAME name,
               DEPT.STATUS status,
               statusT.DESCR statusdesc,
               REL.ROWID_DEPT1 rowidDEPT1,
               REL.ROWID_DEPT2 rowidDEPT2,
               DEPT2.DEPT_FROM_VAL parentcid,
               DEPT2.NAME parentname,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT.CREATE_DATE ORDER BY DEPT.ID) AS rn
          FROM TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT
          LEFT JOIN TEST.STATUS_TABLE statusT
            ON DEPT.STATUS = statusT.STATUS
          LEFT JOIN TEST.C_REL_DEPT rel
            ON DEPT.ID = REL.ROWID_DEPT2
          LEFT JOIN TEST.DEPT_TABLE DEPT2
            ON REL.ROWID_DEPT1 = DEPT2.ID) q
 WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?;  // ? will be fromValue to toValue
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerJob2 {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public CustomerPartitioner customerPartitioner() {
        return new CustomerPartitioner();
    }

    @Bean("readCustomerJob")
    @Primary
    public Job readCustomerJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readCustomerJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(customerStepOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step customerStepOne() throws Exception {    
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("customerStepOne")
                .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), customerPartitioner())
                .step(slaveStep())
                .gridSize(5)
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(3000)
                .reader(pagingItemReader(null, null))
                .writer(customerWriter())
                .listener(customerStepOneExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }


    // Reader
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> pagingItemReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromValue']}") Long fromValue,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toValue']}") Long toValue) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println(" FROM = "+ fromValue + " TO VALUE ="+ toValue);
        
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());
        reader.setSaveState(false);
        reader.setPageSize(3000);
        
        // Sort Keys
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);

        OraclePagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("q.* FROM ( SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY party.ROWID_OBJECT) MyRow, "
                + " OTHER coumns in the Query");

        queryProvider.setFromClause("**** "
                + "LEFT JOIN ********* "
                + "LEFT JOIN ********* "
                + "LEFT JOIN ********* ) q ");
                
        queryProvider.setWhereClause("MyRow BETWEEN "+ fromValue + " AND "+ toValue);
        
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public CustomerWriter customerWriter() {
        return new CustomerWriter();
    }
}
```

Partition Logic

```
public class CustomerPartitioner implements Partitioner{
    private static final String CUSTOMER_CNT = "SELECT COUNT(party.IS) ***** COMPLEX JOIN";
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("edrJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Long custCnt = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(CUSTOMER_CNT, Long.class);
    
        int toValue = 0;
        int fromValue = 0;
        int increment = 3000;
        int counter = 0;
        
        int temp = 0;
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < custCnt; i += increment) { // custCnt fives 100 thousand
            counter++;
            temp = i;           
            if(i == 0) {
                fromValue = temp;               
                toValue = increment;
            }else {
                fromValue = toValue + 1;
                toValue = fromValue + increment - 1;
            }
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.put("fromValue", fromValue);
            context.put("toValue", toValue);
            partitionMap.put("Thread--" + counter, context);
        }
        return partitionMap;
    }
}
```

Here are the logs -

2020-06-22 22:44:14.750  INFO 15752 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=readCustomerJob]] launched with th

```
e following parameters: [{JobID=1592846054670, date=1592846054670}]
2020-06-22 22:44:14.790  INFO 15752 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [customerStepOne]
Cust Count = 1035483
 FROM = 6001 TO VALUE =9000
 FROM = 0 TO VALUE =3000
 FROM = 3001 TO VALUE =6000
 FROM = 9001 TO VALUE =12000
2020-06-22 22:44:15.874 DEBUG 15752 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.b.i.database.JdbcPagingItemReader    : Reading page 0
2020-06-22 22:44:15.874 DEBUG 15752 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.b.i.database.JdbcPagingItemReader    : Reading page 0
2020-06-22 22:44:15.874 DEBUG 15752 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.i.database.JdbcPagingItemReader    : Reading page 0
2020-06-22 22:44:15.874 DEBUG 15752 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.b.i.database.JdbcPagingItemReader    : Reading page 0
```

Comment: How to use nested query in `OraclePagingQueryProvider` ?

Comment: Is `DEPT.ID id` unique?

Comment: Nope, DEPT.ID is not unique, but most entries are unque, when apply LEFT JOIN size of records increases, because one DEPT.ID will have many rows now

Comment: The sort value for the `JdbcPagingItemReader` must be unique so that may cause an issue. However, what is passed to the workers needs to be the unique way of selecting the start and end of the query. The row number won't work unless you select the full set in each worker and filter on the row number.